# Рекурсивный перебор массива булевых значений

Tags: c#, массивы

Есть массив булевых значений, каким способом мне пройтись по всем вариациям массива , делая это рекурсивно?

Comment: Зачем рекурсивно?

Comment: Задача стоит: найти булевые значение при которых булевая формула будет истинна. Сделать рекурсивно.

Comment: @makc2099 У вас есть алгоритм решения вашей задачи?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На i-м уровне рекурсии делайте рекурсивные вызовы со включением i-го элемента и без включения.

```
  func(A[], idx)  {
     if (idx == A.Length()) {
        show A[];
        return; 
     }
     func(A[], idx + 1);
     A[idx] = true;
     func(A[], idx + 1);
}
```

Comment: Но это же не C#.

Comment: Неправильно сформулировал задачу. Мне требуется просто все вариации true или false, количество элементов в массиве такое же.

Comment: @Геннадий П  Это псевдокод. Автор же не показал никаких входных условий.

Comment: @makc2099 Ну какая разница - смотрите с массивом

Comment: @MBo "Псевдокод" не является ответом. Если автор не показал никаких входных условий - значит он неправильно задал вопрос.

Comment: @Геннадий П  `"Псевдокод" не является ответом ` - Вы это серьёзно? Автор испытывает трудности с рекурсией. Понимание её работы и организации  важнее, чем  языковые тонкости.

Comment: @MBo Если ужи пишете ответ, то постарайтесь это делать на предложенном в вопросе ЯП, на C# в данном случае.

Comment: @Геннадий П, ответ пишется не на языке программирования, а на русском языке, и вот это действительно важно.